# AngularJS multiple directıves

Tags: html, angularjs

I tried multiple directives in AngularJS.

```
 var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
 app.controller("myController", function($scope){    });
 app.directive("myDirective1", function(){   return {
    template: "<h1> hello this is directive with template </h1>"   }; });

 app.directive("myDirective2", function(){   return{
     restict: 'A',
     templateUrl: /directiveTry.html   }; });
```

and I have created this main.html:

```
<body ng-controller= "myController as myCtrl">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <my-Directive1></my-Directive1>
    <my-Directive2></my-Directive2>
</body>
```

and directiveTry.html with only one

```
<h1> hello I am external on file </h1>
```

I can't show text. Where is my mistake?

Comment: restict: parameter does not exist. It is `restrict` and A stands for attribute. You are looking for E. Also, you should put the templateUrl value between quotes. It's a string

Comment: ok done, but now not show me the directive2

Comment: The syntax should be `<my-directive...`

Comment: nothing has changed with <my-directive

Answer (score 0):

```
app.directive('myDirective1', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace: 'true',
    template: '<h3>Hello World!!</h3>'
  };
});
```

use as:

```
<my-directive1></my-directive1>
<div my-directive1></div>
```

read any simple articles or watch youtube 'How to create simple directive in angular'
https://www.sitepoint.com/practical-guide-angularjs-directives/

Comment: i have done with template, now i need to show message from external html

Comment: ask google http://techfunda.com/howto/482/custom-directive-with-templateurl

Answer (score 0):

problem solved

a mystake I have forgot an "r"  of restrict 
:(((((

Comment: Yeah... look at my comment.